# How to change system call in gdb or linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, bash, gdb

```
read(fileno(stdin), variable, 1024);
if(strcmp(variable,variable 2 ) == 0) {
    printf("xyz" :)\n\n~$ ");
    fflush(stdout);
    system("/bin/bash -p");
```

Hey Guys,

So I have this C program which contains the following piece of code. So I wan to know if there is any way to change the system("/bin/bash -p") to system("xyz") while executing the program or with gdb.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you first set `/bin/bash -p` to some variable like `char path[] = "/bin/bash -p"` and use `set` command in gdb

`(gdb) set path="new/path/"`